# Why do all values appear True when i type while loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, walrus

I am currently learning  walrus := , and when I do this coding and add to the list and then print it, a list appears with all the items True.

```
foods = []
while food := input("what  food do you like: ") != 'quit':
    foods.append(food)
enter code here
print(foods)
```

Comment: Operator precedence… `(food := input(..)) != 'quit'`

Comment: I think it returns true as the foods entered do not equal quit, so that statement returns true. If you enter quit, the variable food becomes false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The walrus operator assignment has lower precedence as compared to the relational operators. So saying:

```
food := input("what  food do you like: ") != 'quit':
```

Evaluates as

```
food = <result of (input("what  food do you like: ") != 'quit')>
```

And until the input is `quit` it always returns `True` causing all values of `food` to be `True` and foods to be a list of all `True`.
You can try using:

```
(food := input("what  food do you like: ")) != 'quit':
```